# Dynamic function name in Angular 2 click event

Tags: javascript, angular, components, dynamic-function

While this answer is probably dead simple, I seem to be stuck. As an Angular 2 beginner, I have tried all possible combinations of {}, [] and () brackets to achieve the following:

```
<button (click)="this.action">Click me</button>
```

where:

```
this.action = "clickMe()"
```

i.e. it is a string, a name of the method in that component that should be executed on click.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use square bracket syntax like

```
(click)="this[action]()"
```

where

```
action="clickMe"
```

Comment: just mention: the action should be the string of the method name

Comment: This gives me an error like this `error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'Component'.`